# Design of an Automated Employee Scheduling System

Tags: sql-server, database, sharepoint, synchronization, schedule

I would like to design an automated employee scheduling system using SharePoint 2010.

The system aims to facilitate the employees’ needs in order to be able to automatically provide the available data to the user. More specifically, using a schedule system the user should be able to search and find the available resources for a task to do. The user must be able to filter each resource based on their “Skills” and “Attributes” so that the system can assign each resource to a particular task.

Could you please tell me way to do this? Which software are needed to do this, and how do I start? Any links available for help?

Thank you!